# serializer.is_valid() returns 500 Internal server error

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, axios, django-serializer

I am new to Django and have trouble making django-rest-framework API for post, inheriting APIView. I'm using a serializer, that inherits djangos ModelSerializer. I see 500 Internal server error whenever I try validating the serializer.

color.js posts image using Django rest framework as follows.

```
function PersonalColorScreen({navigation,route}) {
    const {image} = route.params;
    console.log('uri is', image.uri);
    const [userToken, setUserToken] = React.useState(route.params?.userToken);

    const requestHeaders = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        }
    }
    // helper function: generate a new file from base64 String
    //convert base64 image data to file object to pass it onto imagefield of serializer.
    //otherwise, serializer outputs 500 Internal server error code

    const dataURLtoFile = (dataurl, filename) => {
    const arr = dataurl.split(',')
    const mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1]
    const bstr = atob(arr[1])
    let n = bstr.length
    const u8arr = new Uint8Array(n)
    while (n) {
      u8arr[n - 1] = bstr.charCodeAt(n - 1)
      n -= 1 // to make eslint happy
    }
    return new File([u8arr], filename, { type: mime })
  }
  //random number between 0-9
  function getRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
  }
  
  // generate file from base64 string
  const file = dataURLtoFile(image.uri, `${getRandomInt(10)}.png`)
  const formData= new FormData();
  formData.append('img',file,file.name);

  console.log(file.name);
    //axios post request to send data
    // axios.post('http://localhost:8000/accounts/personalcolor/',  formData,requestHeaders)
    //multipartparser
    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/accounts/personalcolor/', formData, requestHeaders)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        if (res.data === 'upload another image') {
            setimageError('upload another image');
        } else {
            // signUp(userToken);
            let color;
            switch (res.data){
                case ('spring'):
                    color = 'spring';
                    break;
                case ('summer'):
                    color = 'summer';
                    break;
                case ('fall'):
                    color = 'fall';
                    break;
                case ('winter'):
                    color = 'winter';
                    break;
            }
        }
        })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err.response.data)
    })
```

view.py handles the image posted. I am trying to save the serializer to save the image inside the media folder. The image path should be extracted.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def personalcolor(request):

serializer = ColorSerializer(request.data)
# validation of input data
if serializer.is_valid():
    # serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
else:
    return Response(serializer.errors, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

model.py

```
class Personalcolor(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    img = models.ImageField('personal_img',upload_to="personalcolor/", blank=True)
```

serializer.py

```
class ColorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = Personalcolor
      fields = ('img',)
```

Executing the code returns "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)". I think there is something wrong with serializer but couldn't figure out even after searching online.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You have to use `data` for the `request.data`, so `ColorSerializer(daata=request.data)`

Comment: Thanks. serializer.is_valid() no longer returns errors but serializer.save() returns 500 Internal server error even if it saves the image inside the media folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your JSON format that you are sending is correct. The json key must be the same with your models field name... It must be exactly the way your model field name is structured.

And in you Serializer, change;

`fields = ('img')`

To

`fields = ['img']`

If you want to return all the model instances use;

`fields = '__all__'`

Comment: Thanks. serializer.is_valid() no longer returns errors but serializer.save() returns 500 Internal server error even if it  saves the image inside the media folder.